# Format List View: JSON background colours 'ms-bgColor2' property - very few colours available

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

I'm attempting to change the colour of the bg-Color property.  By standard on my list the colour is set to white.  I'd like to change it to a different colour, but there are very few available to me.  I can pick green, red, yellow, black, purple, blue, orange.  Most of these colours are too dark though.

Are the available colours limited by a theme or a template?  Or does someone have a link to the default colours that are available?

I've attempted to use a value of 'lime', '#00ff00', 'aqua', 'green4' but none of these are recognised it seems - Source of values: [JonasJacek](https://jonasjacek.github.io/colors/), I also checked the [JSON values](https://jonasjacek.github.io/colors/data.json).

I'm trying to make these changes via the 'Format List View' menu - see pic below.

[image: Picture of the Format View JSON menu]

Yellow does work:
[image: Picture of the Format View JSON menu, with value changed to yellow]

(BTW I'm new to SP-Online, have used SP 2010 and 2013 On Premises).

Here's the code, it's all default code, nothing changed by me:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/tile-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": 73,
  "width": 254,
  "hideSelection": false,
  "fillHorizontally": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-card-container"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "button",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-defaultClickButton",
          "role": "presentation"
        },
        "customRowAction": {
          "action": "defaultClick"
        }
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "ms-bgColor-white sp-css-borderColor-neutralLight sp-card-borderHighlight sp-card-subContainer"
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all available classes at: [Reusable SharePoint Online Classes for Modern UI](https://zerg00s.github.io/sp-modern-classes/)

Also, you can apply background color using `style` property, like:

```
"elmType": "div",
   "style": {
      "background-color": "#ff0000"
   }
...
```

You can use any combination of Hex color as per your requirements.